# very strange behaviour of jquery.offset() method

Tags: javascript, html

After doing

```
$view.offset({
   left : X, //X is the same each time
   top : this.y
});
console.log($view.offset()); //outputs what it should
```

for several objects. I saw (in firebug) the following html code

```
<div id="4017" class="text-block" style="position: relative; top: 2px; left: 22px;">
<div id="4043" class="text-block" style="position: relative; top: 41px; left: -64px;">
<div id="4053" class="text-block" style="position: relative; top: 80px; left: -95px;">
<div id="4081" class="text-block" style="position: relative; top: 119px; left: -135px;">
```

`left` should be the same for all divs (and it's displayed so if `left` is equal for each `div`). Why `left` is not the same for each `div` despite it's shown so that `left` is the same for all divs?

In CSS I have:

```
div.text-block {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** divs are located iside three other divs:

```
<div id="app-container">
    <div id="canvas-container">
        <div id="canvas">
            <!-- divs are located here -->
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In respective CSS I have:

```
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#app-container {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#canvas-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can we have a fiddle of your issue so we can look at more of the code

Comment: The value of `X` is being changed somewhere, but we can't tell unless you post more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2),

> .offset( coordinates )
>   **Description:** Set the current coordinates of every element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

So if your elements are in other elements not positioned on position (0, 0) relative to the document, there is an offset applied.

---

**EDIT**

Relatively positioned inline elements with same left value :

[image: Demo picture]

Comment: thank you! I've updated the question, maybe this helps you to understand what's up

Comment: Yes, since your `div` are declared as in `inline-block`, and are positioned relatively, your origin is moved at the end of a block which would have taken the length of your previous block. I know that is not really clear, but I have added a picture where I have forced all `left` position to the same value...

Comment: By the way, if you want to have some same left position in your code, you can write: `$view.css({ position: "relative", left: X, top: this.y });`...

Comment: ,I thought it's just the same, isn't it?